# How can numactl cpunodebind work properly with isolated cpus?

Tags: linux, redhat, scheduling, affinity, numactl

My process has **one high frequency thread** and **several low frequency threads**. I want to bind the high frequency thread A on **an isolated cpu** 18 (of NUMA node 0), and other low frequency threads on other **non-isolated cpu** cores(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,24,26,28,30) of NUMA node 0.

My machine has 32 cores,
numa node 0: 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30
numa node 1: 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31

Firstly, I set the grub booting parameters for isolating CPU cores 17-22:

```
isolcpus=17,18,19,20,21,22 nohz_full=17,18,19,20,21,22
```

Secondly, in the code of thread A(high frequency thread), I bind the thread on core 18 by calling API `sched_setaffinity(...)`.

And then, I start my program by `numactl` command

```
numactl --cpunodebind=0 --membind=0 ./myprogram.sh
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work expectedly. The low frequency threads **all allocated on the isolated core 18**. And I check the `/proc/thread-id/status`, the Allowed Cpu includes all nodes of numa 0, which should excludes the isolated cores 18, 20, 22.

I'm grateful if you would help me. Thanks a lot.

high frequency thread A runs on an isolated cpu 18 (of NUMA node 0), and other low frequency threads run on other non-isolated cpu cores(0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,24,26,28,30) of NUMA node 0.